# multy image render : webgl vs canvas2d

Tags: canvas, webgl2

I want to render 20 image too many times in different places in screen.
I wants to know which of canvas2d or webgl is faster in this case.

I know that Overally webgl is better than canvas but in this case which webgl needs to get pixels color from a 2dtexture array and getting size of that image to be render) from another texture, isn't this reading data from texture make it slower than canvas? 
while canvas just needed to call `drawImage()`

thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you just try both?

Comment: you mean that I should test it in the case?